# Loop-Created Matrices in Julia

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia

Let's say we have arrays u and v, and function f. We want a matrix F consisting of f(ui, vi) for all members of u and v.
Trying this:

```
F = [ [f(ui,vi) for vi in v] for ui in u]
```

The result is an array of arrays (In Julia's words, `Array{Array{Int64,1},1}`)

How can I reshape this into a 2-dimensional array? (`Array{Int64,2}`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of two nested comprehensions, just use one [multidimensional comprehension](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/arrays/#comprehensions):

```
F = [f(ui,vi) for vi in v, ui in u]
```

Comment: Thank you! Wouldn't that be `for ui in u, vi in v` though?

Comment: It depends on the dimension you want to be contiguous (and therefore faster).  In your original example, the inner arrays are contiguous, with each one iterating across `v` for an element in `u`.  The order I listed is similar since Julia is column major.  Each column iterates over `v` for one element in `u`.